# Column and Row Alignment In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm given a question in which I am required to randomly generate a multiple between 10 and 100 inclusive in Cell A, an integer between 1 and 3 inclusive in Cell B. In Cells C and D, I must:
If Cells B in the corresponding column and row line up respectively, print half the value of A, or otherwise, 0.

I've randomly generated a multiple between 10 and 100 inclusive in Cell A, and an integer between 1 and 3 inclusive in Cell B. Yet, I don't understand what I have to do for cells C and D. I hear that it is necessary to employ a formula using the XOR and IF function, but I don't understand what it means for a corresponding column and row to line up respectively. B has pseudorandom numerical inputs, but how does that gel with the notion of the row and column aligning?
Below is an image of the task I am required to complete (I am experiencing difficulty with Q5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch0uK.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser,,, it's quit interesting issue,, could U plz share some sample data along with the original question, help us to understand and fix it !

Comment: @Rajesh S I'm not certain I'll be able to succinctly explain it here, but the main gist of my question is wanting to know exactly what it means for a corresponding column and row to line up respectively. I'll post an image to give some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if the three numbers in a row of Bs are identical, then produce the calculation as described in the D cell for that row.  Similarly if the three numbers in a column of Bs are identical, produce the calculation in the C cell for that column.

I don't think it would be right to give you the exact answer here.

However, you can check if multiple logical conditions are all TRUE using the AND function. You can then use IF to decide what to do in case the AND function returns TRUE or FALSE.

Good luck with your assignment.

Comment: It makes a whole great deal of logical sense now. What I need from the first paragraph was essential.

Comment: Hi @Owen add some screen shot will make the answer much better.